# Django: How to pass value from one CBV to another

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to customize django authentications forms/templates. URL /accounts/password_reset/ (CBV:PasswordResetView) is used to enter account email. After form submitting user redirected to  /accounts/password_reset/done/ (CBV:PasswordResetDoneView)

I need to use email value in PasswordResetDoneView. How can I do it?

Sorry for newbie question.

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('accounts/password_reset/', views.CustomPasswordReset.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('accounts/password_reset/done/', views.CustomPasswordResetDone.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    # ...
]
```

views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from .forms import LoginForm, ResetForm, NewPasswordForm

class CustomPasswordReset(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    template_name = 'authorization/password_reset_form.html'
    html_email_template_name = 'authorization/password_reset_email_html.html'
    email_template_name = 'authorization/password_reset_email_plain.html'
    subject_template_name = 'authorization/password_reset_subject.txt'


class CustomPasswordResetDone(auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView):
    template_name = 'authorization/password_reset_done.html'

    # TODO. I have no idea how to get email address that was entered in 'password_reset' step
    # 
    email = 'example@gmail.com'
    mbox, mserver = email.split('@')
    extra_context = {'mserver': mserver}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Django's [session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. Thank you, I'll study this part of django.